# How to read a big binary file and split its content by some marker

Tags: python

In Python, reading a big *text* file line-by-line is simple:

```
for line in open('somefile', 'r'): ...
```

But how to read a binary file and 'split' (by generator) its content by some given marker, not the newline '\n'?

I want something like that:

```
content = open('somefile', 'r').read()
result = content.split('some_marker')
```

but, of course, memory-efficient (the file is around 70GB). Of course, we can't read the file by every byte (it'll be too slow because of the HDD nature).

The 'chunks' length (the data between those markers) might differ, theoretically from 1 byte to megabytes.

So, to give an example to sum up, the data looks like that (digits mean bytes here, the data is in a binary format):

```
12345223-MARKER-3492-MARKER-34834983428623762374632784-MARKER-888-MARKER-...
```

Is there any simple way to do that (not implementing reading in chunks, splitting the chunks, remembering tails etc.)?

Comment: It's not the hard disk that makes 1-byte-at-a-time slow, it's the function call overhead that'll peg your CPU.

Answer (score 6):

There is no magic in Python that will do it for you, but it's not hard to write. For example:

```
def split_file(fp, marker):
    BLOCKSIZE = 4096
    result = []
    current = ''
    for block in iter(lambda: fp.read(BLOCKSIZE), ''):
        current += block
        while 1:
            markerpos = current.find(marker)
            if markerpos == -1:
                break
            result.append(current[:markerpos])
            current = current[markerpos + len(marker):]
    result.append(current)
    return result
```

Memory usage of this function can be further reduced by turning it into a generator, i.e. converting `result.append(...)` to `yield ...`. This is left as an excercise to the reader.

Answer (score 2):

A general idea is using `mmap` you can then `re.finditer` over it:

```
import mmap
import re

with open('somefile', 'rb') as fin:
  mf = mmap.mmap(fin.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
  markers = re.finditer('(.*?)MARKER', mf)
  for marker in markers:
    print marker.group(1)
```

I haven't tested, but you may want a `(.*?)(MARKER|$)` or similar in there as well.

Then, it's down to the OS to provide the necessaries for access to the file.

Comment: Using `mmap` is a neat idea; the only downside is that it will only work for regular files.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any built-in function for that, but you can "read-in-chunks" nicely with an iterator to prevent memory-inefficiency, similarly to @user4815162342 's suggestion:

```
def split_by_marker(f, marker = "-MARKER-", block_size = 4096):
    current = ''
    while True:
        block = f.read(block_size)
        if not block: # end-of-file
            yield current
            return
        current += block
        while True:
            markerpos = current.find(marker)
            if markerpos < 0:
                break
            yield current[:markerpos]
            current = current[markerpos + len(marker):]
```

This way you won't save all the results in the memory at once, and you can still iterate it like:

```
for line in split_by_marker(open(filename, 'rb')): ...
```

Just make sure that each "line" does not take too much memory...

Comment: This implementation is incorrect: it will fail to split by markers found in the last block, if there was more than one. As the OP correctly surmised, getting this right is trickier than it seems.

Comment: Also, `function(open(...))` is an anti-pattern because it relies on reference counting to close the file as function exits. The preferred idiom is `with open(...) as f: function(f)`

Comment: It wasn't an issue with the last block, but an issue with multiple markers in the same block. And I don't think that relying on reference counting is such a bad habit in small python scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Readline itself reads in chunks, splits the chunks, remembers tails, etc.  So, no.